# Xcode 7.3, MacOS 10.11.4, Unity 5.3.2f1. Cardboard SDK for Unity v0.6 not working

Tags: xcode, google-cardboard

I have Xcode 7.3, MacOS 10.11.4, Unity 5.3.2f1.
I’ve got Cardboard SDK for Unity v0.6 from official site. (cardboard-unity-master.zip)

I followed all your instructions indicated on official  site.
In Unity everything is working well. But I can’t run the app on the iPhone.
[image: error pic1]

I tried to turn OFF «Enable Bitcode»...

[image: error pic2]

But I have a few errors too...

[image: error pic3]

Help me to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. "In the XCode project open the project view and select the tab 'Build Phases'. Towards the bottom of that view there is 'Link Binary With Libraries' at the bottom of which are two buttons + and -. Click the + button and from the list select 'Security Framework' and press Add."